# A Linear Algebra Problem; functions

Tags: computational-complexity, recursion

[image: Problem on Linear Algebra][[Problem on Linear Algebra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2hqR.png)
How to approach the problem? I have no idea how to start with and solve.

Comment: What's the source of this question, please?

Answer (score 0):

From the information given, you should be able to construct formulas that give you $M_n$ and $A_n$ just from the value of $n$. The trick is to find the pattern that relates $n$ to the number of additions and multiplications performed. A good place to start is just to look at the ones that are apparent. Using the first four equations we can obtain: $$A_0=0, A_1=1, A_2=2, A_3=3$$ $$M_0=0, M_1=0, M_2=1, M_3=1$$

Comment: what about A20172017?